# Horizontally stacking anchor tags to 100% of container

Tags: css

This seems like it should be really simple, but I'm having a CSS moment..

One div, with three `<a>`'s in it, each of which have a `display` of `inline-block` and `width` of 33%. Why does the last one drop onto a new line?

Css

```
div {
  width:100%;
  background-color:pink;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width:33%;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px 0px;
}
```

The result, which can be seen in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xa23RKpKRINzkHs5kio2?p=preview):

[image]

Comment: Because at that screen width, `99%+30px > 100%`? If you make the results section in your plunkr wider, they all end up on the same line.

Comment: The padding is only applied vertically.

Comment: Cheers. But I don't get it. I can set the padding to 0, and it still needs a wide results section to not wrap.. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the whitespace between your `<a>` tags.  If you put all of them on the same line, they will always fit.  You can see the gap in the screenshot you posted.  There is a space between the green and orange.

Comment: Bingo. I was wondering why that space was there, hence messing about with margin and padding.